Proxmox storage full and unable to clear
I received status io error couple days ago and my VM quit working. After clearing some iso images I can get my VM running again. Problem now is, my /dev/sbd1 is showing 91% full.
This particular drive stores my plexmediaserver and all of it's media. I went in via filezilla and deleted ALL my media. Yet, it's still showing me 91% usage in /mnt/pve/Storage.
I am at my wit's end with this. Any advice is greatly appreciated.
Specs:
Proxmox 7.3-3
Running plexmediaserver and transmission-daemon on ubuntu server.
root@proxmox:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 3.2G  1.3M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/pve-root  450G  103G  329G  24% /
tmpfs                  16G   46M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb1             932G  843G   89G  91% /mnt/pve/Storage
/dev/fuse             128M   20K  128M   1% /etc/pve
tmpfs                 3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0

So I figured I should look at the dir on a high level.
root@proxmox:/# du -ah . | sort -rh | head -n 10
du: cannot access './proc/376983/task/376983/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/376983/task/376983/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/376983/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/376983/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
939G    .
836G    ./mnt/pve/Storage/images
836G    ./mnt/pve/Storage
836G    ./mnt/pve
836G    ./mnt
639G    ./mnt/pve/Storage/images/103/vm-103-disk-0.qcow2
639G    ./mnt/pve/Storage/images/103
99G     ./var
97G     ./var/lib/vz
97G     ./var/lib

Seems like ./var/lib and ./var/lib/vz are my biggest issues. So I tried drilling into them.
root@proxmox:/var/lib# du -ah . | sort -rh | head -n 10
97G     ./vz
97G     .
96G     ./vz/images
45G     ./vz/images/100/vm-100-disk-0.qcow2
45G     ./vz/images/100
43G     ./vz/images/108/vm-108-disk-0.raw
43G     ./vz/images/108
8.5G    ./vz/images/105/vm-105-disk-1.qcow2
8.5G    ./vz/images/105
1.4G    ./vz/template/iso/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso
root@proxmox:/var/lib# cd ./vz
root@proxmox:/var/lib/vz# ls -l
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 30  2023 dump
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul  2  2023 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 30  2023 private
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 30  2023 snippets
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 30  2023 template
root@proxmox:/var/lib/vz# du -ah . | sort -rh | head -n 10
97G     .
96G     ./images
45G     ./images/100/vm-100-disk-0.qcow2
45G     ./images/100
43G     ./images/108/vm-108-disk-0.raw
43G     ./images/108
8.5G    ./images/105/vm-105-disk-1.qcow2
8.5G    ./images/105
1.4G    ./template/iso/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso
1.4G    ./template/iso

cd into ./images
root@proxmox:/var/lib/vz/images# ls
100  105  108

These 100 numbers are just my VMs running in proxmox specifically in this disk. 108 is my plexmediaserver which suppose to have the most storage used but when i run df -h it's barely used!
james@media-server:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              794M  1.1M  793M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  981G   19G  922G   2% /
tmpfs                              3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  253M  1.6G  14% /boot
tmpfs                              794M  4.0K  794M   1% /run/user/1000

As i mentioned, i was having issues with status io error so i already deleted all my media in this VM to eliminate the media being the issue. I've also checked VMs 100 and 105, they are not taking up that large a space that would cause sbd1 in my root proxmox shell to show that my /mnt/pve/Storage to be 91% used.
I suspect it's cache leftover that I am unable to clear by deleting all my media from plexmediaserver. But I've hit a wall with this as well.
I am quite at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

@NikitaKipriyanov outputs of the commands you suggested I run.
root@proxmox:~# cat /etc/pve/storage.cfg
dir: local
        path /var/lib/vz
        content backup,rootdir,images,snippets,vztmpl,iso
        shared 0

dir: Storage
        path /mnt/pve/Storage
        content iso,rootdir,backup,vztmpl,snippets,images
        is_mountpoint 1
        nodes proxmox

root@proxmox:~# lvs
  LV   VG  Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root pve -wi-ao---- <457.26g                                                    
  swap pve -wi-ao----    8.00g  

I don't fully understand your answer and have several follow up questions:

pve/root is the default installer iso for proxmox? and it is huge, does this mean my install of proxmox on my bare hardware is taking up a lot of space? How can I resolve this, and could it be due to poor provisioning when I installed proxmox in the first place?


Also, how did you happen to have pve/root of 450G (!), it's very large and the default installer never creates such a large root volume?


I ran fstrim -av on all my vms including the host shell. It didn't produce an output despite the verbose flag. I assume it worked in the background (?).

I ran lsblk --discard on my host shell, here's the output. Pardon my understanding of this phrase:



Non-zero values will indicate that you have it enabled;

Does my output show that discard is enabled? If no, how can I enable discard?
root@proxmox:~# lsblk --discard
NAME         DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
loop0               0        4K       4G         0
loop1               0        4K       4G         0
sda                 0      512B       2G         0
├─sda1              0      512B       2G         0
├─sda2              0      512B       2G         0
└─sda3              0      512B       2G         0
  ├─pve-swap        0      512B       2G         0
  └─pve-root        0      512B       2G         0
sdb                 0        0B       0B         0
└─sdb1              0        0B       0B         0

I really appreciate your patience as I am pretty new to the whole storage concepts in proxmox. The reading materials you linked are greatly helpful!

Do not post images. Use the codeblocks to post the commands and their output.

Thank you for the advice @NasirRiley. I've amended the post to adhere to the guidelines.

please, show the output of cat /etc/pve/storage.cfg and lvs. Also, how did you happen to have pve/root of 450G (!), it's very large and the default installer never creates such a large root volume? Also try to run fstrim -a in each VM and pct fstrim <PCT_ID> on the host for each CT, to reclaim the unused but still mapped storage


91% is 89G in your case, which is a plenty of storage. It shouldn't cause any issues.

This is standard situation with any thinly provisioned storage (not just virtual machines). When you store data, it allocates blocks for that, so the back-end storage maps them. When you delete files, you mark some blocks in the filesystem metadata as unused; however, the data is still there and these blocks are still mapped in the underlying thin storage.


Precisely this is the issue ATA TRIM / SCSI UNMAP commands are designed to address. These are commands to tell the storage that certain blocks are not used anymore and can be reused.
In Proxmox, to be able to use any of these in the VM, you have to enable discards on the virtual disk, as explained in the documentation. See also here. I'd rather say you better have this always enabled for all the disks.
Having done that, run lsblk --discard in the VM. Non-zero values will indicate that you have it enabled; then, use e.g. fstrim -a on a regular basis, add discard into your mounting options in fstab or whatever is applicable to your system. Windows has similar functionality enabled by default since Server 2012, if I am not mistaken.
With containers, you run pct fstrim <CT ID> on the host to reclaim space, see here.

P.S. Proxmox 7 is  outdated. It's time to upgrade, that's easy.

Thank you. I've successfully enabled discard on all my vm and running sudo fstrim -av cleared all the cache in my /storage dir. Very grateful for you advice!

This is not a "cache" in any way. These blocks are mapped (e.g. used from the standpoint of the host) but unused in the filesystem (in the VM). You made the filesystem to tell the host which blocks are unused so it unmapped them, freeing the space.

Gotcha, that makes sense!

Yes, by the way, this is exactly what is written in the answer. Only with different wording.
